# Access variables from another class (Java)

Tags: java, class, object

i didnt programm for a while and just started a new project to refresh my java skills/get better, so this might be a dumb question.

First i'll provide my code. Its just a sample program so there is no actual panel to click on but it doesnt matter for my question.

Main:

```
package sample;

public class main {
    class1 c1 = new class1();
}
```

class1:

```
package sample;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class class1 {

    int var1 = 0;
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();

    public class1(){
        jp.addMouseListener(new MouseListenerClass());
        jp.setName("Test");
    }

}
```

MouseListenerClass:

```
package sample;

import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MouseListenerClass extends MouseAdapter
{
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me)
    {
          JPanel jp1 =(JPanel) me.getSource();
          System.out.println(""+jp1.getName());
    }
}
```

How can i access a variable(e.g. var1) from my class1 when im inside the mousePressed method inside my MouseListenerClass/another method in another class.

Greetings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just pass an instance of one class to the other one, and have a getter for the field:

```
public class UIClass {
    private int number = 42;
    private JPanel jp = new JPanel();

    public UIClass() {
        jp.addMouseListener(new MouseListenerClass(this));
        jp.setName("test");
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
}

public class MouseListenerClass extends MouseAdapter {
    private UIClass uiclass;

    public MouseListenerClass(UIClass uiclass) {
        this.uiclass = uiclass;
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
        JPanel jp1 = (JPanel) me.getSource();
        System.out.println(jp1.getName());
        System.out.println(uiclass.getNumber());
    }
}
```

Notes: I changed the name from `class1` to `UIClass` since the former doesn't follow the standard Java convention of class names beginning with uppercase letters, and I removed the `""+` from the line that prints `jp1.getName()` since it's presumably already returning a string, and even if it isn't, there is an overload of `System.out.println` that takes an `Object` and calls `toString()` on it.

Comment: Hey,thanks for your answer. Is passing an instance to every class that i use one of its methods/variables in a good practice or are there better ways to do it?

Comment: @Sakkath Yes, this is a good practice. Of course, instead of passing it to the constructor, you could pass it in to a `setter` later, which is basically what `addActionListener` is.

Comment: @Sakkath: Better to separate the model -- the underlying logic, state and behavior of your program -- from the view -- the GUI, and one way to do this is via the M-V-C or Model-View-Controller design pattern. There are several reasons that this is beneficial, one being to reduce connectedness (or "coupling") of code making for fewer bugs, another being ease in upgrading, the other being ease in changing GUI platforms, e.g., change from Swing to JavaFX.